# Gtk (mm) limit width of combobox

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

Because I use Comboboxes that may contain text entries of very long size,
which leads to the combobox increasing its width far beyond reasonable size,
I am trying to give a maximum width to the combobox.

If I am doing this like this:

```
class MyCombo : public Gtk::ComboBox {
    private:
        CellRendererText render;
    public:
        MyCombo() {
            render.property_width_chars() = 10;
            render.property_ellipsize() = Pango::ELLIPSIZE_END;
            pack_start(render, true);
        }
};
```

The result will be an empty cell of the desired width, which seems logical since I did not specify which column to show. But how can I do this with that attempt? Using `pack_start` will just bypass the renderer...

Another approach is this one:

```
class MyCombo : public Gtk::ComboBox {
    private:
        CellRendererText render;
    public:
        MyCombo() {
            pack_start(render, true);
            set_cell_data_func(render, sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyCombo::render_iter));
        }

        void render_iter(const TreeModel::const_iterator& iter) {
            Glib::ustring data = get_string_from_iter(iter);
            int desired_width_chars = 10; //for example
            render.property_text() = ellipsize_string(data, desired_width_chars);
        }
};
```

Using that approach, it works, but the text in the popup (what opens up when u click the combobox) is also shortened which is not what I want (obviously the user should be able to read the whole string and I dont care about the popup widht.)

Can you please help me with this? I would be happy for any advice/alternative solutions.

Regards tagelicht

Comment: So you want to limit the width of the combobox but not limit the width of the combobox popup?

Comment: exactly. And I m really desperate about this as this seems to be common behaviour and I just dont get how to achieve it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** `set_wrap_width` is a function that wraps the total number of entries in the combo box over a number of columns specified; it does not answer the question.

*Using set_wrap_width(1) | Using set_wrap_width(5)*

[image]
[image]

---

Following Noup's answer as a guide I managed to get the below code; which directly answers the question and its requirements (C++/Gtkmm).

```cpp
    // Get the first cell renderer of the ComboBox. 
    auto v_cellRenderer = (Gtk::CellRendererText*)v_comboBox.get_first_cell();

    // Probably obsolete; Sets character width to 1.
    v_cellRenderer->property_width_chars() = 1;

    // Sets the ellipses ("...") to be at the end, where text overflows.
    // See Pango::ELLIPSIZE enum for other values.
    v_cellRenderer->property_ellipsize() = Pango::ELLIPSIZE_END;

    // Sets the size of the box, change this to suit your needs. 
    // -1 sets it to automatic scaling: (width, height).
    v_cellRenderer->set_fixed_size(200, -1);
```

Result (image):
[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMvff.png)

**BE AWARE:** Depending on where you perform the above code; either all the cells will be the same size, or just the box itself (intended).
From experimenting, I've found:

- **In the parent object constructor:** All cell sizes are the same.
- **In a separate function:** Only the first cell (the box) is affected.

I'd recommend you put the code in a function that's connected to the comboBox's changed signal, such as:

```
    v_comboBox.signal_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &YourClass::comboBox_changedFunction));
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
cell_renderer_text.set_wrap_width(10)
```

This is for Python, but you get the idea :-)

Unfortunately, the documentation is scarce. I found this by poking around in Anjuta/Glade.

**Edit:**

the docs are [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererText.html#GtkCellRendererText--wrap-width). They are not overly helpful, but they do exist.

Comment: Thats perfect thanks :) it works like a charm.... but you are right the documentation is HORRIBLE... I spent hours searching for this before asking and all those properties got not any documentation at all...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, the following works for me without having to set wrap_width nor to subclass ComboBox (in Gtk#):

```cs
ComboBoxText cb = new ComboBoxText();
cb.Hexpand = true; //If there's available space, we use it
CellRendererText renderer = (cb.Cells[0] as CellRendererText); //Get the ComboBoxText only renderer
renderer.WidthChars = 20; //Always show at least 20 chars
renderer.Ellipsize = Pango.EllipsizeMode.End;
```

Note: I'm using Expand to use space if it's available. If you just want to keep the combo box on a fixed width, just remove that bit.